# SQL 2012 - How can I convert MultiLineString to Geography?

Tags: geometry, sql-server, geography

I have a Geometry LineString that I wish to convert to Geography.
Since the Geometry isn't valid , When I use MakeValid on it, SQL convert it to MultiLineString and than the Geography creation is failing with error :

```
The specified input does not represent a valid geography instance. Use MakeValid to convert the instance to a valid instance. Note that MakeValid may cause the points of a spatial instance to shift slightly.
```

What can I do in order to convert the Geometry to Geography ?

Geometry text : http://pastebin.com/Ly8ex41U

Geometry text after MakeValid : http://pastebin.com/HGNFKnS3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I grabbed your after text from pastebin and did

```
SELECT geography::STGeomFromText([your text], 4326)
```

and got no error.  How are you trying to create your geography?

I did find that

```
SELECT geography::STGeomFromText([your text], 4326).MakeValid()
```

converted it to a GeometryCollection.

Comment: I'm using SQL 2012 , Doing the same as you :
DECLARE @g NVARCHAR(max)
SET @g = [text from paste]
SELECT Geography::STGeomFromText(@g, 4326)

And I'm getting error :
Msg 6522, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined routine or aggregate "geography": 
System.ArgumentException: 24200: The specified input does not represent a valid geography instance. Use MakeValid to convert the instance to a valid instance. Note that MakeValid may cause the points of a spatial instance to shift slightly.

Comment: Specifically, I tested with SQL 2012 Express version 11.0.2100.60 and in-lined the text rather than assigning (not that I would expect that to make a difference).

Comment: I have no idea how come it works for you and not for me.
very very strange.

Can you load it into SQL Fiddle or send me your script so ill run it?

I'm running on :
Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio      11.0.2100.60
Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC)      6.1.7601.17514
Microsoft MSXML      3.0 4.0 6.0 
Microsoft Internet Explorer      9.10.9200.16635
Microsoft .NET Framework      4.0.30319.18052
Operating System      6.1.7601

Comment: Something very strange happening now.
Query DOES work on master , but doesn't work on my DB which is in the same instance.

Any idea ?!

Comment: I've solved it.
My DB was import from 2008. I've created new one , imported only the data and tables and now it works. so weird.